# flex content breaks in child element but not in parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flex box

```
<div className="details">
   <div className="name">Name: {name}</div>
        <span className="bullet"></span>
   <div className="age">Age: {age}</div>
        <span className="bullet"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

But when the name is really long it breaks weirdly.

[image]

Everything breaks instead of the age just wrapping underneath the name. How do I achieve this with css?

As of now my css is very bare:

```
.details {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.name, .age {
     color: #575757;
     word-wrap: break-word;
}

.bullet {
     background-color: #575757;
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
     margin: auto 4px;
     border-radius: 100%;
}
```

How can I make it so that when the name is long, the bullet and age move underneath it at the start of a new line and not this weird break?

Comment: Seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/m9sov63p/1/

Comment: it stacks all the elements on top of each other. At least in my browser. I want it to continue underneath

Comment: Flex items are unbreakable boxes. They don't break across lines.

Comment: so the entire details div would need to be its own thing ur saying

Comment: If you want text to wrap across lines, stick with block layout. This is how text flows around images, using block layout and floats.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you have missed a quote?

```
<div className="details"> <!--  changed here -->
   <div className="name">Name: {name}</div>
        <span className="bullet"></span>
   <div className="age">Age: {age}</div>
        <span className="bullet"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a typo. Was copying from my code because the class names were more complicated lol. just fixed it. However, no the issue is still present.